# php select query with different date formats

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable called $date with a date format like 2012-01-30. On the other hand I have a field called srt_date_sortie in a mysql table. The format of that field is like 2012-01-30 11:31:00. I would like to select all records where $date and srt_date_sortie have equal dates not taking into consideration the time. Hope someone can help.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorties WHERE srt_date_sortie = '$date'");
```

Here below how I build $date :

```
++$input;
$test=$input." days";
$date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($test));
```

Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons you should avoid comparing against a derived column like `DATE(srt_date_sortie)` as this will prevent any indexes from being used. This negates a few of the solutions already posted.

The most efficient way of querying against your `DATETIME` field is by using a range query like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorties WHERE srt_date_sortie BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'");
```

Unless you need all of the rows from the table the `SELECT *` could be inefficient, just list the rows that you need to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you James for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query with BETWEEN keyword for date start time and end time.

Answer (score 0):

You can format date using [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in mysql

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorties 
             WHERE DATE_FORMAT(srt_date_sortie,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$date'");
```

Comment: Hello Click. Unfortunately your suggestion is not working. Thank you anyway very much for trying to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorties WHERE DATE(srt_date_sortie) = '$date'");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: This method is inefficient and will cause a full table-scan (see my explanation below)

Comment: @JamesC That depends on situation. In some cases, as you, I think, know, keys are harmful to performance. But, in most cases, I`d agree with you.

Comment: Timur. In >99% of cases keys aren't harmful to performance. That's the point of them ;)

Comment: Hmm... I`ll not agree with you. I had a lot of examples where keys must not be used. Or it was better to use another type (for example, covering index). But this is not a about of this question, I guess. If we continue discussion, it would be offtop. Just read about situation where indexes must not be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorties WHERE srt_date_sortie  LIKE '%2012-01-30%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($test));
```

Use it

Answer (score 0):

Check the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) mysql function

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01');
        -> 3
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');
        -> -1
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
        -> 128885
```